# How to export Pytorch model to ONNX with variable-length tensor loop?

Tags: pytorch, export, onnx, onnxruntime

I simplify my complex Pytoch model like belows.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
import onnx
import onnxruntime
import numpy as np


class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.template = torch.randn((1000, 1000))

    def forward(self, points):
        template = self.template
        points = points.reshape(-1, 2)
        heatmaps = [template[point[0]:point[0] + 10, point[1]:point[1] + 20] for point in points]
        return heatmaps


model = Model()
points = torch.randint(100, 200, (1, 8, 2))


torch.onnx.export(model, args=points, f='toy.onnx',
                  export_params=True,
                  opset_version=13,
                  do_constant_folding=True,
                  verbose=False,
                  input_names=['input1'],
                  output_names=['output1'],
                  dynamic_axes={'input1': {0: 'batch_size'},
                                'output1': {0: 'batch_size'},
                                }
                  )

session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession("./toy.onnx")
inputs = np.random.randint(100, 200, (2, 8, 2))
ort_inputs = {'input1': inputs}
ort_outs = session.run(None, ort_inputs)
```

I can export Pytoch model to ONNX successfully, but when I change input batch size I got errors.

```
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running Split node. Name:'Split_3' Status Message: Cannot split using values in 'split' attribute. Axis=0 Input shape={16,2} NumOutputs=8 Num entries in 'split' (must equal number of outputs) was 8 Sum of sizes in 'split' (must equal size of selected axis) was 8
```

I know this error caused by loop through a dynamic sized tensor, but I don't know how to solve this problem. **Note, I cannot move this operation out of model due to some restrictions.**

Any suggestions will help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this list comprehension

```py
heatmaps = [template[point[0]:point[0] + 10, point[1]:point[1] + 20] for point in points]
```

Here during the export, when tracing over the tensor `points`, the number of iterations is saved as a constant in the resulting ONNX model. So when you try to run the model with a different batch size, it's still assuming that there are eight points (the number you exported it with) and crashes.

The simplest solution is to define the loop using the input tensor

```py
    def forward(self, points):
        template = self.template
        points = points.reshape(-1, 2)
        n_points = points.size(0)
        heatmaps = torch.zeros((n_points, 10, 20))
        for i in range(n_points):
            heatmaps[i] = template[points[i, 0]:points[i, 0] + 10, points[i, 1]:points[i, 1] + 20]
        return heatmaps
```

Now the number of iterations is a variable depending on the shape of `points`, and the ONNX model runs with any batch size. Although there most likely is a more elegant solution without using for-loops at all.

Also, you might find this interesting [torch.nn.functional.grid_sample](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.grid_sample.html)